# Pull request build from Azure in Jenkins?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

We are migrating our gitlab projects to AzureDevOps.
Currently, our projects in gitlab are configured with a webhook, which triggers a jenkins build on every commmit.
The jenkins build pipeline is written in groovy, and has a different flow when it comes to merge requests. We make use of the branch name in the following manner:   `( if (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /MR-.*/) { do some checks }`

In our first step of migration, we plan to move away from gitlab to azure git. The commits to azure repos should still trigger the jenkins.
I am not having an idea as to how to deal with merge requests. Currently, I see that there is no branch created while creating a PR in azure. As a result I cannot make use of  `( if (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /PR-.*/) { do some checks }`  Any suggestions to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used Jenkins in anger so I can't remember what environment variables are available. However the branch name for a pull request will be `merge`

The full "path" to the branch will look something like `refs/pull/123/merge` where `123` is the pull request number.

Note that this information comes from the [Azure Pipeline docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) so YMMV in Jenkins (look for Build.SourceBranch)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at our own builds (we use Azure DevOps Pipelines), pull request branches look like:

> - [new branch]      feature/80536-*** -> origin/feature/80536-***
> - [new ref]         refs/pull/15000/merge -> pull/15000/merge

Notice the `refs/pull/{PR-ID}/merge` pattern.

Also, for the webhook trigger, you probably would need to utilize the "Pull request merge attempted" event:

[image: Jenkins Service Hook]

Hope it helps,